# pytest module import ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, python-module

This question has been asked *DOZENS* of times before, but every one I've come across doesn't have any working solutions for me.

I'm using Python 2.7 and `pytest` to run tests.

Structure is as follows (from the root of my project/git repo):

```
myapp/
    myapp/
        __init__.py           # def main():
                              #    ... stuff
                              # if __name__ == "__main__":
                              #    main()

        __main__.py           # import __init__ as myapp
                              # myapp.main()

        config.yaml           # (app config file)

        myapplib/
                __init__.py   # (Empty file)

                config.py     # Loads {projectroot}/config.yaml
                              # def cfg(): 
                              #    ... stuff
    tests/
        test_stuff.py         # from myapplib.config import cfg
```

I then try to run the tests/test_stuff.py file by doing:

```
cd {projectroot}
pytest
```

And it complains:

```
myapp/tests/test_stuff.py:38: in <module>
    from myapplib.config import cfg
E   ImportError: No module named myapp.config
```

---

Some things I've tried:

1. Using `-m` to import `myapplib` or `myapp.myapplib`
2. Starting `pytest` from a different dir (e.g. inside tests/)
3. Using all the path hacks in all the other answers
4. Changing it to `from . import XXX` or `..` or any of the relative import options (but these all fail with `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`.

Worth nothing that the app itself executes fine from the project dir:

```
cd {projectroot}
python myapp
```

... and all config and paths work just fine. It's just the tests that can't find the path.

---

Here's a complete reproduction of what I have so far:

https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/4fa60f5a-02df-43bb-8aa3-03e59ff72650/?m=Saved%20fiddle

Comment: it seems that `myapp.config` doesnt exist. Shouldn't it be `myapp.myapplib.config` ? the error doesn't seem to match your code.

Comment: Yep, tried that too, which just complains `ImportError: No module named myapp.myapplib.config`

Comment: Yep, tried that too 

Comment: I mean you say your code is `from myapplib.config import cfg` but the error states `from myapp.config import cfg`. Clarify that first

Comment: Ha, whoops red herring. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're running

```
myapp/tests/test_stuff.py
```

you need to edit the path in `test_stuff.py` to point to `myapp` (which contains `__init__.py`)

I tested this on my system (file `test_stuff.py`):

```
import sys,os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),os.pardir,"myapp"))
import myapplib
```

(getting full path of your python module, then using parent dir to add the python path to just the second level of `myapp`)

works on my dirtree configured like yours:

```
S:\python\myapp\myapp
S:\python\myapp\tests
S:\python\myapp\myapp\myapplib
S:\python\myapp\myapp\myapplib\__init__.py
S:\python\myapp\tests\test_stuff.py
```

Advice: when fiddling with `sys.path.append()`:

- always use absolute paths, using `__file__` to make sure that the current directory doesn't get in the way. *never* depend on the current directory, or this trick will only work when in a given directory.
- debug: print the path you're adding to check if it's the proper one. Since it's absolute, you'll easily see if it's correct.

Comment: Alright, I must be doing something wrong. I added the path.append() to `/myapp/__init__.py`, and still no dice. I created a brand new project just to be safe, and still nothing. For what it's worth, from that path string I'm getting `myapp/../myapp`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with a complete reproduction of my test project with your changes: https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/4fa60f5a-02df-43bb-8aa3-03e59ff72650/?m=Saved%20fiddle

Comment: @brandonscript seems that there's a confusion here. The snippet I mentionned must be in `test_stuff.py`. you put my code in myapp init instead... BTW fiddle doesn't care about your triple quote filenames. It just ignores them, uses "main.py".

Comment: Ohhh I see, your answer made it should like I was supposed to put it in __init__.py. That doesn’t make much sense, does it ;). And yes- the fiddle was just me trying to keep it all in one place rather than separate files.

Comment: altering the `sys.path` only works for the one which imports the module. I have edited my post to clear the confusion

Comment: Yeah, that makes way more sense. Want to edit the q to make that more clear? I’ll accept - it works now.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. your question error is `myapp/tests/test_stuff.py:38: in <module>
    from myapplib.config import cfg`. Glad that it worked, cos I put some effort reproducing your file tree :)

Comment: I edited the part that confused me. Let me know if that’s ok!