# ModuleNotFoundError with pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pytest

I want my [tests folder separate](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code) to my application code. My project structure is like so

```
myproject/
  myproject/
    myproject.py
    moduleone.py
  tests/
    myproject_test.py
```

myproject.py

```
from moduleone import ModuleOne

class MyProject(object)
....
```

myproject_test.py

```
from myproject.myproject import MyProject
import pytest

...
```

I use `myproject.myproject` since I use the command

```
python -m pytest
```

from the project root directory `./myproject/`

However, then the imports within those modules fail with

> E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'moduleone'

I am running Python 3.7 and have read that since 3.3, empty `__init__` files are no longer needed which means my project becomes an [implicit namespace package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52812525/817379)

However, I have tried adding an `__init__.py` file in `myproject/myproject/` and also tried adding a `conftest.py` file in `myproject/` but  neither works

I have [read answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48694855/817379) that say to [mess with the paths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49605901/817379) and then upvoted comments in other questions saying [not to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49723266/817379).

What is the correct way and what am I missing?

**EDIT;**

Possibly related, I used a `requirements.txt` to install pytest using pip. Could this be related? And if so, what is the correct way to install pytest in this case?

**EDIT 2:**

One of the paths in `sys.path` is `/usr/src/app/` which is a docker volume lined to `/my/local/path/myproject/`.

Should the volume be `/my/local/path/myproject/myproject/` instead?

Comment: Honestly, this is going to be a opinion war if anything. You could move the test folder into your main structure and execute it from there, and your could would work as-is. Wouldn't need to change a thing since the import paths would be relevant. Other than that, you would need to monkey-patch the path in the test-files to include the target directory, and it wouldn't be a bad thing (opinion). Just know why and what you're doing.

Comment: Long comments.. You could also (on your command line) append the `PYTHONPATH` to include the target directory. Meaning you wouldn't have to manipulate `sys.path` from any of your scripts, but you would get a updated path upon running the test. `PYTHONPATH=./myproject python -m pytest` as if you did.

Comment: Of the directories you listed in the project structure, which (if any) are in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: @JohnGordon updated the question with new info

Comment: have you tried adding the empty __init__.py to the ./tests directory instead of your project directory. It might sound strange, but worth trying.

Comment: I solved my problem with a tox.ini file. I run pytest same path of my tox.ini
`[pytest]¶testpaths=testdir/¶pythonpath=parent/of/moduledir¶`

Comment: reference: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference/reference.html#confval-pythonpath

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### Solution: use the `PYTHONPATH` env. var

```sh
PYTHONPATH=. pytest
```

As mentioned by @J_H, you need to explicitly add the root directory of your project, since `pytest` only adds to `sys.path` directories where test files are (which is why @Mak2006's answer worked.)

---

#### Good practice: use a Makefile or some other automation tool

If you do not want to type that long command all the time, one option is to create a [`Makefile`](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/what-how-makefile) in your project's root dir with, e.g., the following:

```
.PHONY: test
test:
    PYTHONPATH=. pytest
```

Which allows you to simply run:

```sh
make test
```

Another common alternative is to use some standard testing tool, such as [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Just a minor note: makefiles require tabs for indentation, so copy pasting your code might not work since it uses spaces.

Comment: Thanks @SilverSlash! The source code actually uses tabs, but, indeed, it is rendered as spaces in the answer. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think that's a limitation of HTML and web browsers, unfortunately.

Comment: Halleluja. WHY? <insert meme here>

Answer (score 84):

Not sure if this solution was specific to my problem, but I simply add `__init__.py` to my `tests` folder and that solved the problem.

Comment: This does the trick, thanks. May I know why it changes pytest import behavior by adding a __init__.py in tests folder?

Comment: worked for me too, however is this bad practise?

Comment: My `tests` folder already had an `__init__.py` file, so I can confirm that this solution is not universal.

Comment: @huichen `__init__.py` tells Python that the folder is a module. Without it, the folder is not a module and so Python cannot find its name when used in `import` statements.

Answer (score 20):

Be sure to include `.` dot in the `$PYTHONPATH` env var.

Use `$ python -m site`, or this code fragment to debug such issues:

```
import pprint
import sys
pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

---

Your question managed to use `myproject` at three different levels. At least during debugging you might want to use three distinct names, to reduce possible confusion.

Answer (score 18):

In my case I added a `__init__.py` to my test directory with this inside it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

My app code is at the same level as my test directory.

Comment: Adding this fixed my issue.

Comment: I added an empty __init__.py file and it worked as well.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I moved `tests` to the same level as my app code. Then, I made an `__init__.py` file with the code described above. Finally, my `pytest.ini` file was empty too and I was able to run `pytest` successfully.

Answer (score 12):

In 2023.02, according to the [document of pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.2.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#test-discovery), you can simply add following config to your pyproject.toml to solve this problem

```
[tool.pytest.ini_options]
pythonpath = "src"
addopts = [
    "--import-mode=importlib",
]
```

Comment: This is the way to go these days. This answer should be either accepted as the ideal answer or voted higher up. Also heads up, the value of `pythonpath` will be the "_root_" of the project and not necessarily `src` (unless `src` itself is the root for your project).

Answer (score 9):

In my case it is because I installed `pytest` on the system level but not in my virtual environment.

You can test this by `python -m pytest`. If you see `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'` then your `pytest` is at the system level.

Install `pytest` when the virtual environment is activated will fix this.

Comment: In my case, it's installed on both system and virtualenv level. But only `python3 -m pytest` works.

Comment: This was the issue with my system. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

### Better Solution

Try adding a single `__init__.py` to your tests directory (a level up from your module) with this contents:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
sys.path.append('./my_module')
```

Your file structure should look like this:

```
project
  my_module
    package.py
  tests
    __init__.py
    my_tests.py
```

The first append to `sys.path` will enable you to import from `<your-module-name>` and the second will enable your packages to import as normal.

In your tests you can import by using `from my_module.package import function` whereas in your module import using simply `from package import function`.

---

Edit: Seems like this solution is not universal (like the others).

I was able to solve this issue using help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69691436/11922567).
Add an `__init__.py` to your main module directory that contains

```py
import pathlib, sys
sys.path.append(str(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent))
```

I also added another `__init__.py` to my `tests` directory (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258928/11922567)) with

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('.')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Had a similar issue. Solved my problem

Comment: This worked great for me and it is simple.

Answer (score 5):

**Kept everything same and just added a blank test file at the root folder ..** Solved

Here are the findings, this problem really bugged me for a while. 
My folder structure was

```
mathapp/
    - server.py  
    - configuration.py 
    - __init__.py 
    - static/ 
       - home.html  
tests/            
    - functional 
       - test_errors.py 
    - unit  
       - test_add.py
```

and pytest would complain with the ModuleNotFoundError.

I introduced a mock test file at the same level as mathsapp and tests directory. The file contained nothing. Now pytest does not complain.

Result without the file

```
$ pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\mak2006\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont
collected 1 item / 1 error

=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR collecting tests/functional/test_func.py ________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\mainak\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont\tests\functional\test_func.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests\functional\test_func.py:4: in <module>
    from mathapp.service import sum
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mathapp'
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR tests/functional/test_func.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
============================== 1 error in 0.24s ===============================
```

Results with the file

```
$ pytest
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.2, pytest-5.4.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\mak2006\workspace\0github\python-rest-app-cont
collected 2 items

tests\functional\test_func.py .                                          [ 50%]
tests\unit\test_unit.py .                                                [100%]

============================== 2 passed in 0.11s ==============================
```

Answer (score 2):

So it seems that the `sys.path` has to include **the application directory** rather than the project root folder containing the application directory and test directory.

So in my case `/my/local/path/myproject/myproject/` had to be in `sys.path` rather than `/my/local/path/myproject/`.

Then I could run `pytest` in `/my/local/path/myproject/` (didn't need `python -m pytest`). This meant that the modules within `/myproject/myproject/` could find each other and the tests as well without any namespace nesting.

So my tests looked like

```
 from moduleone import ModuleOne
 import pytest

 def test_fun():
     assert ModuleOne.example_func() == True
```

That said, there seem to be [many gotchas](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#tests-outside-application-code), so I have no idea if this is correct..

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a code structure like this:

```
myproject/
  helpers/
    moduleone.py
    moduletwo.py
  tests/
    myproject_test.py
  conftest.py
```

And the content of conftest.py file is:

```
pytest_plugins = ['helpers']
```

Run `pytest` again.

Comment: what is the purpose of `pytest_plugins = ['helpers']`

Comment: Replacing `helpers` with the name of your module. Pytest will read this line and add the your module. Therefore, resolve the `ModuleNotFoundError` issue

Answer (score 1):

Using poetry and pytest 5.4.3, I had the following structure (some folders / files have been removed for clarity):

##### project structure

```
.
├── my_app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── model.py
│   └── orm.py
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.rst
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── test_my_app.py
    └── utilities
        └── db_postgresql_inmemory.py
```

##### tests/conftest.py

```
pytest_plugins = [
    "utilities.db_postgresql_inmemory",
]
```

which generated a module not found error for the fixture:

```
ImportError: Error importing plugin "utilities.db_postgresql_inmemory": No module named 'utilities'
```

None of the other answers have worked for me, as I have tried to add:

```
[me@linux ~/code/my_app]touch tests/utilities/__init__.py
[me@linux ~/code/my_app]touch ./test_blank.py
```

I could make the import from conftest.py work by **REMOVING** both `__init__.py` files:

```
[me@linux ~/code/my_app]rm tests/utilities/__init__.py tests/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and am using poetry for dependency management and direnv for my project specific environment variables. Please note, I am relatively new to Python so I don't know if this is the correct fix.

Here is my entire .envrc file:

```
layout_poetry() {
  if [[ ! -f pyproject.toml ]]; then
    log_error 'No pyproject.toml found.  Use `poetry new` or `poetry init` to create one first.'
    exit 2
  fi

  local VENV=$(poetry env list --full-path | cut -d' ' -f1)
  if [[ -z $VENV || ! -d $VENV/bin ]]; then
    log_error 'No created poetry virtual environment found.  Use `poetry install` to create one first.'
    exit 2
  fi
  VENV=$VENV/bin
  export VIRTUAL_ENV=$(echo "$VENV" | rev | cut -d'/' -f2- | rev)
  export POETRY_ACTIVE=1
  PATH_add "$VENV"
}

layout poetry
export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/project_name"
```

I don't know if I need to layout poetry because it is supposed to be creating virtual environments for us already but this is what I coworker recommended so I went with it. Layout poetry also didn't work without that function and it didn't like when I added it to my zshenv so I added it here.

For this specific question, the last line is the money maker.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue which i resolved by

- Installing `pytest` at the root of my project using `pip install pytest`
- Adding blank `__init__.py` in the sibling of my `test_file.py` which i wanted to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it by adding export PYTHONPATH="your root dir/src"

i.e.
export PYTHONPATH="/builds/project/src"

poetry run pytest .....

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I found was to manually add my target module to syspath. Lets say you have a structure like this:

```
flaskapp
- src
  -- app.py
  -- utils
  -- ...
- tests
docs
venv
```

This makes my `test` folder a sibling to my module's `src` folder. If I start putting `test_*` files that need to import some of the module's code, I can simply:

```
import src.utils.calculator
```

And this would be fine until I try to import a file that imports another file from the module. The solution is simple: add a `__init__.py` to your `tests` folder, and put this line inside:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../src')))
```

And just modify the last part relative to your module location and folder name

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I was checking my project structure I found parent directory and sub directory having same names. When I changed the directory name, I got it working. So,

```
# Did not work
- same_name_project/
    - same_name_project/
    - tests/

# Worked
- different_named_project/
    - a_unique_directory/
    - tests/
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the import in the **myproject.py** looks like this:

```
from moduleone import ModuleOne
```

try replacing the path with the full one, like

```
from myproject.moduleone import ModuleOne
```

the initial error looks logical, because there is no moduleone module in the tests directory from which the program is run

it helped in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).